# Espresso Android test - Check is IntroductoryOverlay is active

Tags: android, android-espresso

It it possible to check using Android Espresso Is IntroductoryOverlay is active?

If yes, how can I dissmiss IntroductoryOverlay in my test?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `ViewAction` to dismiss a `IntroductoryOverlay` via its [remove](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/IntroductoryOverlay#remove()) function:

```
fun hideIntroductoryOverlay(): ViewAction = object : ViewAction {

    override fun getDescription(): String = "hide introductory overlay"

    override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> = isRoot()

    override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
        val matcher = any(IntroductoryOverlay::class.java)
        val matches = TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(view).filter(matcher::matches)
        val overlay = matches[0] as IntroductoryOverlay
        overlay.remove()
    }
}
```

If the filter returns an empty array, it means no `IntroductoryOverlay` is found. If the array size is greater than 1, it means more than one `IntroductoryOverlay` are found. Otherwise to dismiss it:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(hideIntroductoryOverlay())
```

You can also check if an `IntroductoryOverlay` is active with a custom `ViewMatcher`:

```
fun hasIntroductoryOverlay(): Matcher<View> = object : BoundedMatcher<View, ViewGroup>(ViewGroup::class.java) {

    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("has introductory overlay")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: ViewGroup): Boolean {
        val matcher = any(IntroductoryOverlay::class.java)
        return TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(item).any(matcher::matches)
    }
}
```

And perform the check on root view:

```
onView(isRoot()).check(matches(hasIntroductoryOverlay()))
```